# Group by 1-7 System date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below, and I need to group by week (system date)

```
 tran_date      Hours   Tech_ID Tech_Name
02/02/2019 16:30    1   310091  Nasser Ahmed Muhammad
02/02/2019 17:30    8   310094  Ajish Babu Parambath
03/02/2019 08:30    8   310380  Nishad Mulayath Mohanan
04/02/2019 08:30    8   310380  Nishad Mulayath Mohanan
04/02/2019 08:30    8   310094  Ajish Babu Parambath
05/02/2019 08:30    1   310091  Nasser Ahmed Muhammad
06/02/2019 08:30    1   310380  Nishad Mulayath Mohanan
06/02/2019 08:30    5   310094  Ajish Babu Parambath
09/02/2019 09:30    3   310091  Nasser Ahmed Muhammad
09/02/2019 09:30    3   310094  Ajish Babu Parambath
09/02/2019 11:00    1   310380  Nishad Mulayath Mohanan
09/02/2019 13:30    1   310380  Nishad Mulayath Mohanan
09/02/2019 13:30    1   310091  Nasser Ahmed Muhammad
09/02/2019 14:30    1   310094  Ajish Babu Parambath
09/02/2019 16:30    2   310094  Ajish Babu Parambath
10/02/2019 08:30    1   310094  Ajish Babu Parambath
10/02/2019 08:30    2   310380  Nishad Mulayath Mohanan
10/02/2019 09:30    1   310094  Ajish Babu Parambath
10/02/2019 10:30    2   310091  Nasser Ahmed Muhammad
10/02/2019 13:30    1   310380  Nishad Mulayath Mohanan
10/02/2019 13:30    2   310094  Ajish Babu Parambath
10/02/2019 14:30    1   310380  Nishad Mulayath Mohanan
10/02/2019 15:30    1   310094  Ajish Babu Parambath
10/02/2019 16:30    1   310094  Ajish Babu Parambath
13/02/2019 08:30    4   310380  Nishad Mulayath Mohanan
14/02/2019 13:30    1   310091  Nasser Ahmed Muhammad
14/02/2019 14:30    0.5 310091  Nasser Ahmed Muhammad
```

Im expecting a result like below.

```
tran_week              Total
2/1/2019 - 2/7/2019    40
2/8/2019 - 2/14/2019   29.5
```

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk, tran_date) wkno,
Concat(SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS 
DATE)) ,'-',
DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) )
tran_week ,SUM(Hours) TotalHours FROM   table_name
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, tran_date)
```

Comment: But be sure to test dates around new year's as well, since as far as I know SQL server is not able to change the rules that define which week is week 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like following.

```
;with cte as 
(
 select cast(tran_date as date) tran_date, Hours
 from @mytable
)

SELECT Convert(varchar, WS, 101) + '-' + Convert(varchar, WE, 101) AS trans_week ,SUM(HOURS) Total FROM
(
    SELECT      DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, tran_date)-1), tran_date) WS, DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, tran_date)), tran_date) WE
            ,   Hours           
    FROM        cte
)
T
GROUP BY WS,WE
order by ws
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/ZUAFUI5086)

**Note:** If you want to change the first day of week you need to first set it like following.

```
SET DATEFIRST 6
```

[SET DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The dates are repeating.

Answer (score 0):

If you generate the the string of select part of the query by your programming language of choice then the below code shall work so will be able to calculate the hours:

```
    select 
      sum (case when t.tran_date between  range1_1 and  range1_2 then t.hours else 0 end) as range1,
      sum (case when t.tran_date between  range2_1 and  range2_2 then t.hours else 0 end) as range2,
      sum (case when t.tran_date between  range3_1 and  range3_2 then t.hours else 0 end) as range3,
      sum (case when t.tran_date between  range3_1 and  range4_2 then t.hours else 0 end) as range4,
  ...
  from your_table as t
```